# Bus between Gothenburg Landvetter Airport and the city centre

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, sweden, got, gothenburg

I am visiting Gothenburg in Sweden.  I read on the [Landvetter Airport website](http://www.swedavia.com/landvetter/to-from/bus/) that there are buses running between the airport and the city centre (that are *not* the Flygbuss Airport coaches), but the links there led me to no additional information.  Does anybody know any information about those buses, e.g., the lines, the fares, the timetables, or better, a webpage containing all the information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Flixbus](http://www.flixbus.se/) also travels between Landvetter airport and Gothenburg (Nils Ericson terminalen). Prices on Flixbus are generally cheaper (29-69 SEK), but buses travel less frequently: there are about seven or eight buses every day, as compared to 89 SEK on [Flygbussarna](http://www.flygbussarna.se/en/Landvetter), which travel every 20 minutes. Granted, prices are still more than one is comfortable to pay for such small distance, but there's nothing to be done about it. All the [schedules are here](http://www.outofyourcomfortzone.net/the-cheapest-way-to-get-from-gothenburg-landvetter-airport-to-the-city-center/).

The price difference is small enough that you should just prefer Flygbussarna -- their tickets are valid for 3 months and you don't have to book a specific time or date in advance.  If Gothenburg is not your final stop, you might want to check Flixbus tickets to other destinations which pass through Landvetter airport.

There are no other bus operators to and from the airport. [Västtrafik](http://www.vasttrafik.se/) used to have service to the airport (lines 511 an 616, if memory serves), but not any longer as of 15 December 2013. I couldn't find the official announcement, but [Göteborg Posten has an article about it](http://www.gp.se/nyheter/goteborg/1.2187082-dyrare-ta-sig-med-buss-till-landvetter) (in Swedish).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and the advice!  The link to the newspaper article is especially helpful.